# Function that receive two variables and decides which statistical analysis should be done

Tags: categorical-data, continuous-data, function

I am trying to create a function that receives two variables (dependent and independent) and figures out according to their class (numeric / factor) and number of groups, which statistical test should be done (t.test, Kruskal - Wallis, chi-square, etc..)

My code so far:

```
my_function (x, y){
if(is.numeric(x) & is.numeric (y)){
c=cor.test(x,y)
print(paste("a correlation test is done, pv is",c$p.value)
}
if(is.factor (x) & is.factor (y){
m = chisq.test(x,y)
print(paste("a chi test is done, pv is", m$p.value)
}
}
#######
variable1 = diamonds$carat
variable2 = diamonds$depth
my_function(x=variable1 , y=variable2)
```

This code doesn't account for a case where I have one continues variable and one dichotomous variable whereas a T.test is warranted if is normally distributed or K-W test is warranted otherwise.
also doesn't account for number of groups in the grouping variable.

I'd appreciate any help

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What do you want to test? My answer about what test to run, even for normal distributions, will be drastically different if you want to know about differences in means than if you want to know about differences in variances.

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid that this vastly oversimplifies how good analysis is done. I won't rule out the possibility that a lot of analysis may be automated in the future, but we're not there yet. And even then, analytical choices won't be decided solely based on the type of the predictor and response. Without some knowledge about the nature of the *research question*, it's near-impossible to provide reliable advice about a specific procedure/model/test to use.

Comment: Can you provide please a basic univariable analysis function including simple tests like (t.test, K-W, chi- sqaure, etc..)

Comment: @SariKatish No. Questions about code are off-topic here and as I explained, *this is a bad idea*.

Comment: +1 One of my jobs was trying to make some kind of decision tree about analysis to run (not quite software automation but similar in spirit). I, the lone statistician on the team, was tasked with creating this decision tree, and every leaf contained a comment along the lines of, “Consult with your statistician.”